# The iterating polygons increasing by length of 10 px eachtime don't center perfectly with its inner polygon. What could the maths after line 11 be?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Why don't the iterating polygons not align perfectly. (if I try to make a polygon with 4 sides, it works fine, but any other shape and it aligns a bit differently). Is it something to do from line 11 to line 16?
[This is the question I am trying to solve with my function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCbKh.png)

```py
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(5) 

def draw_shape(length, sides, colores, times):
 for timestotal in range(1, times+1):
   for side in range(sides):
     t.color(colores)
     t.forward(length*timestotal)
    t.right(360/sides)
  t.penup()
  t.back(length*2)
  t.left(360/sides)
  t.forward(length*2)
  t.right(360/sides)
  t.pendown()

draw_shape(4, 8, "red", 8)
```

It doesn't really matter if it is ascending or descending lengths as long as all the shapes are centered as is in the exercise.

[Unfortunately if the parameter is anything other than 4 the shapes do not align properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjKSm.png)

[If I pass different commands between penup() and pendown() for each number from 3 to 13 using if, elif, and else statements, it does align the shapes but each number(length) needs its own sets of code:](https://www.pythonsandbox.com/code/pythonsandbox_u33847_YQml4loiGzc1NzDB3NhbcDnD_v1.py)

Could it be something around this command:

```
t.goto(-(lengthtimestotal)/2,(lengthtimestotal)/2)
```

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem can be reduced to "draw a regular polygon of `n` sides from a center point". If you can do that, then you need only iterate with different sizes in the outer loop, all drawing from the same point (the turtle's current location).

I don't think it's easy to draw a regular polygon from a center point using only `forward`, `backward` and turning commands. But it's possible to use the classic trig polygon approach to compute the vertices of the polygon around the circle:

```py
import turtle
from math import cos, radians, sin


def draw_shape(length, color, sides, times):
    t.color(color)
    x, y = t.pos()
    side = 360 // sides

    for i in range(times):
        current_length = length // times * (1 + i)
        t.penup()

        for angle in range(0, 361, side):
            t.goto(
                current_length * cos(radians(angle - side / 2)) + x,
                current_length * sin(radians(angle - side / 2)) + y
            )
            t.pendown()


t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(5)
draw_shape(length=100, color="red", sides=8, times=5)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

The `angle - side / 2` bit is used to rotate the polygon by half a side to match the spec.

I also see `draw_shape(100, "blue", 4, 3)` has unusual output. You can get this with `current_length = length - (20 * i)` which hardcodes the step size. Not very pleasant to have to do, but such it is.